# How to set input value in a component with if else condition

Tags: angular

I have a question about can I set input value in a component with if else condition

example:

```
a self defined component 

<self-defined-component></self-defined-component>

in this component I have defined input parameters such as

<self-defined-component [input-parameter] = "some input"></self-defined-component>

Can I use: 
<self-defined-component [input-parameter] = "isValid ? 'some input' : 'undefined'"></self-defined-component>
```

any solutions?

Comment: Well, did you try it? If so, did it work?

Comment: `Can I set input value in a component with if else condition` Yes, you can! Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: The tenary seems fine for me, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes although you would be setting a string value of 'undefined' there rather than the primitive value undefined.

Comment: my problem is with translation, I set input variable such as [headerTitle]="isvalid ? ''title' | translate' : ' ' "..

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I think the problem ist because of tranlstion

Comment: @user1938143 - Then add in the question the full line of code that uses that pipe.

Answer (score 0):

For this we, could bind the value returning from a method which could have the if else condition. So the below snippet would help you on this scenario:

```
<self-defined-component [input-parameter] = "getInputData()"></self-defined-component>
```

In TS:

```
public getInputData(): any{
   if(condition1){
      return someValue;
   } else {
      return someOtherValue;
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.